# How can I make a `Partial<T>` but only for nullable fields?

Tags: typescript

I need a `Partial<T>` like mapped type that allows me make nullable fields optional. I'm working on typing our ORM and it coerces undefined to nulls on nullable fields.

I'd like to take a type of

```
interface User {
  email: string
  name: string | null
}
```

And make

```
interface User {
  email: string
  name?: string | null
}
```

I tried

```
type NullablePartial<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends null ? T[P] | undefined : T[P] }
```

But `extends null` doesn't work for the union of `null` and another type (and I'd ideally like it to work with more than strings). And the difference between optional fields and undefined values is important.

What can I do?

Comment: Try `null extends T[P] ?` instead of `T[P] extends null ?`, since you're asking if `null` is assignable to `T[P]` ("yes" for `string | null`, "no" for `string`), not if `T[P]` is assignable to `null` (which is just "no" unless `T[P]` is `null` or `never`)

Comment: Of course this doesn't make the new `User` have optional properties, just adds `| undefined` to the value type.  The true answer will be a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making a type function turn just *some* properties optional or non-optional is actually quite annoying in TypeScript, because there's no simple way to describe it.  The easiest way I can think to do it is using multiple [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).  Here's something that should work as long as the type you pass in doesn't have an index signature (it gets more complicated):

```
type NullablePartial<
  T,
  NK extends keyof T = { [K in keyof T]: null extends T[K] ? K : never }[keyof T],
  NP = Partial<Pick<T, NK>> & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, NK>>
> = { [K in keyof NP]: NP[K] }
```

Note that I'm using [`Pick`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1432-L1437) and [`Exclude`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1446-L1449) to carve up `T` into the nullable properties and the non-nullable properties, doing different things to each of them, then intersecting them back together.  Determining nullable properties has to do with checking if `null extends T[K]` (i.e., "can I assign `null` to this property"), not the reverse (i.e., "can I assign this property to a variable of type `null`").

I'm also using [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to make the type manipulation more concise (so I only have to determine the nullable property key names once as `NP`) and to make the final output type more aesthetically pleasing (by doing one final mapped type at the end I get a type that is not represented as an intersection).

Let's try it on:

```
interface User {
  email: string
  name: string | null
}

type NPUser = NullablePartial<User>;
// type NPUser = {
//  name?: string | null | undefined;
//  email: string;
// }
```

Looks reasonable to me... is that close to what you wanted?  Good luck.

Comment: The error messages from that are crazy! But it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: What error messages?  Don’t see any in my environment

Answer (score 10):

Let's start by finding which properties are nullable.

```
type NullablePropertyOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: null extends T[K]
    ? K
    : never
}[keyof T]
```

We need to modify nullable properties, but leave the rest unaffected. In order to ignore the non-nullable ones in our transformation, we will need the well-known `Omit` helper.

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Our final product is created by merging the *weak*, partial version of the entire `T` with the properties that were supposed to remain unaffected.

```
type NullablePartial<T> = Partial<T> & Omit<T, NullablePropertyOf<T>>;
```

There is, of course, more than one way to do it. In this example, I'm *optionalizing* everything and *requiring* what's required. You could take the opposite approach: pick the non-nullable fields first, and optionalize the nullable ones, then merge both types. Whatever suits you.

Answer (score 4):

Just changing a little the bit the original `Partial`.

Partial:
`type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] };`

NullablePartial:
`type NullablePartial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | null };`

Comment: This makes everything partial.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm not sure what the difference between this and using optional interface properties would be at that point.

Something like:

```
export interface foo {
   bar?: string;    // nullable
   baz: string;
   bat: boolean;
   etcd?: boolean;  // nullable
}
```

Would that not work in your case?

Comment: on the way out of the db the values are actually null

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you need, but this has allowed me to allow both undefined and null on an interface

```
type NullablePartial<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[keyof T] extends null
    ? null
    : T[K];
};
```